# Where are the Rosicrucian Original Texts in Latin or German (online or offline)?

Tags: german-language, latin-language

Looking [here](https://www.crcsite.org/rosicrucian-library/), there are 3 or 4 texts which I can only find English translations of online. Do the original German or Latin ones exist anywhere online or off?

- Fama Fraternitatis
- Confessio Fraternitatis
- The Chymical Wedding of C.R.C.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Is this the complete list of texts you want to find or are these just examples? (Based on a quick search, Fama Fraternitatis appears to be a collection of texts rather than a single text.)

Comment: I just want to find some example texts in text format online :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Generally asking ["where to find"](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/should-questions-asking-about-availability-of-a-specific-book-be-on-topic) specific works is considered off-topic here.

Comment: @Skooba [This meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209/17) might be more relevant. I'm not sure I understand exactly what this question is asking (hence not voting on it), but asking about translations/availability of *specific* works is generally OK, while asking for whole lists/classes of works is usually too broad or off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fama Fraternitatis is available in German at:

- [Allgemeine und General-Reformation der ganzen weiten Welt beneben der Fama Fraternitatis](http://www.12koerbe.de/lapsitexillis/fama.htm) on 12koerbe.de,
- [Fama Fraternitatis des löblichen Ordens des Rosencreutzes](https://www.anthroweb.info/erweiterungen/quellen/fama-fraternitatis.html) on anthroweb.info (translation into modern German),
- [Fama fraternitatis, oder, Entdeckung der Brüderschafft des löblichen Ordens dess Rosen Creutzes : beneben der Confession, oder, Bekantnus derselben Fraternitet ...](https://archive.org/details/famafraternitati00andr/page/n6/mode/2up) (scan of an edtion from 1615).

Confessio Fraternitatis is available in German at:

- [Confessio Fraternitatis Oder Bekanntnuß der löblichen Bruderschafft deß hochgeehrten Rosen Creutzes an die Gelehrten Europae geschrieben](http://www.12koerbe.de/lapsitexillis/confess.htm#Characteres%20und%20Buchstaben%20der%20Schrift%20der%20Natur) on 12koerbe.de,
- [Confession, oder, Bekantnus der löblichen Bruderschaft ...](https://archive.org/details/famafraternitati00andr/page/54/mode/2up) (scan of an edition from 1615, in the same volume as "Fama fraternitatis", listed above),
- [Confessio Fraternitatis](https://www.anthroweb.info/erweiterungen/quellen/confessio-fraternitatis.html) on anthroweb.info (translation into modern German).

The Chymical Wedding of C.R.C. is available in German at:

- [Johann Valentin Andreae: Chymische Hochzeit: Christiani Rosencreutz Anno 1459](http://www.12koerbe.de/lapsitexillis/chym.htm) on 12koerbe.de,
- [Chymische Hochzeit, by Rosencreutz, Christian](https://archive.org/details/chymischehochzei00rose/page/n5/mode/2up) (scanned version of an edition from 1616),
- [Andreä, Johann Valentin: Chymische Hochzeit Christiani Rosencreutz Anno 1459. Straßburg, 1616](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/valentin_hochzeit_1616?p=7) on DeutschesTextArchiv.de (scanned image and text side by side),
- [Chymische Hochzeit Christiani Rosenkreutz](https://www.anthroweb.info/erweiterungen/quellen/chymische-hochzeit.html) on anthroweb.info.